# What causes an imbalanced battery discharge? Does it indicate a problem?

Tags: batteries, discharge, nimh

I've got a project that uses two AAA batteries in series (no center tap.) I've been using eneloop NiMH batteries. It seems like often if I let the system run until the batteries cut out, one is discharged down to a few hundred mV, and the other is still at 1.2V.

Does this indicate a problem with the circuit, or is this normal behavior for NiMHs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normal behavior for NiMH cells - if you are maltreating them.

The ["Battery University" says you should stop discharge at about 1.0 V per cell.](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-501-basics-about-discharging) That's the level at which most of the energy in NiMH cells is exhausted. It is not a good idea to discharge the cells below that level.

The cell that is discharged to below 1.2 V has a lower capacity than the other one. It will keep getting worse as time goes on. At some point, it will be "reverse charged" by the current from the cell with higher capacity - the voltage on its terminals will be reversed. The cell will probably be damaged beyond recovery at that point.

You need to incorporate a low voltage shutoff in your device.  It should shut off the device to prevent over discharge. At the very least it should warn you when the voltage drops too low so that you will stop using it.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!

Originally, I attempted to have a cutoff like this, using this appnote: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva836a/snva836a.pdf
I had successfully implemented this in other projects, but this one didn't behave - though, maybe it's because I was using 1.8V as a cutoff instead of 2V.

Without the latch circuit, what ends up happening is a bootloop - batteries can't support the load, boost converter shuts off, load is removed, battery voltage rises, boost converter re-enables, batteries can't support load, etc.

Any suggestions? Maybe I'll revisit the latch.

Answer (score 1):

The batteries (when fully charged) do not have identical total charge. There is some difference. That is life. The cell voltage drops of very quickly once the low voltage limit is reached. Most cells are not allowed to reach this point if properly used.

> Does this indicate a problem with the circuit, or is this normal behavior for NiMHs?

This is normal behaviour for NiMH and all cells. It is one reason why Lithium batteries should have an electronic battery management system.

Answer (score 0):

The cell do not have identical capacity. Even if all cells start from 100 % full, the charge in the cell with the lowest capacity is depleted first, even though charge remains in other cells in series.

> Does this indicate a problem with the circuit, or is this normal behavior for NiMHs?

This is normal behavior for all cells.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is normal for rechargeables. It would of helped if a different cutoff was used for NIMH chargers. cutting off the charge after the voltage stops rising past a certain level/15 minute charger, 5-10 seconds, 1C rate, 1 minute, 2C rate 30 seconds .2C rate, the 2amp for 10AH d cell, 4-5 minutes, looks like this would have worked better than a voltage drop that can be easily missed.